# Check if list of string contains object property value, and if it does remove it from the list of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have this list of strings:

```
List<string> clubs = dropdownSelectedvalue.Split(',').ToList();
```

The values will be for example: 1255,1233,2233. Now I have object which has the same propertyid as the values in the clubs list. What I want to achieve is clear out the clubs list from the existing propertyid's in case the id is in the list and only leave the ids which are not existing.

This is the object:

```
public class Clubs
{
    public int? ClubId { get; set; }    
    public string ClubName { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any linq command or something similar which I can utilize for this issue?

Code added:

```
List<string> newClubs = clubs.Remove(s => Club.ClubId.ToString().Equals(clubs));
```

Something like this but it's not completed, I've reached that point.

Additional code added per request:

```
List<Clubs> Clubs = Clubs.LoadAll();
foreach (Clubs club in Clubs)
{
    var dropdownSelectedvalue = values[sponsor.WebUserId.Value.ToString()];
    List<string> clubs = dropdownSelectedvalue.Split(',').ToList();             
    List<string> newClubs = ?                
}
```

Comment: `Is there any linq command or something similar which I can utilize for this issue?` Yes there is. Any other question?

Comment: The reason you are getting downvotes is we'd like to see what LINQ operators you've tried and where you've gotten stuck with your own implementation.

Comment: @KirkWoll L.B I've added code sample of what I've tried (incomplete). Thanks

Comment: @Laziale, what is your source list that contains the existing clubs?  Is it a variable?  Is it a single club?  Can you show that code?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most readable way would be:-

```
var newClubs = clubs.Except(allClubs).ToList();
```

and you would implemnt `IEquatable<Club>` on your clubs class.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx

Or, if you want to deal only in strings, project your allClubs list to just the names of the clubs (using `Select`) and then use `Except` on the strings.

Answer (score 2):

English:  Give me all clubs WHERE my list of club IDs does not CONTAIN the club's `ClubId`

Linq:

```
var query = clubList.Where(c => !clubs.Contains(c.ClubID));
```

Comment: is it possible a new list of strings to be generated from the filtered list? query.ToLIst() is giving me empty list of strings. Thanks

Comment: @Laziale Not sure I follow - are you wanting a list of clubs or a list of strings?  If you want a list of the club Names just add `.Select(c=>c.ClubName)` to the end.